# Spring MockMvc UnsupportedOperationException after upgrading to new spring version

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-test

I'm working on migration from Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE to Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE. 
I got stuck because existing tests start failing. My code looks like (simplified):

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TestConfig.class])
class MvcTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context
    MockMvc mockMvc

    @Subject
    MyController controller

    def setup() {
        controller = new MyController()
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build()
    }

    def "should not allow to save an invalid entity"() {
    when:

    def result = mockMvc.perform(post("/people")
                                         .content('''{
                                            "name": "",
                                            "age": 21,
                                            "sex": 1
                                         }''')
                                         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                         .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

    then:
    result.andDo(print())
          .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
          .andExpect(jsonPath('$.message').value("Name cannot be empty."))
    }
}
```

**MyController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            value = "/people", 
            produces = "application/json", 
            consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Response create(@RequestBody @Valid Person person) {
        //save person to repository. Debugger is not even entering this line...
    }
}
```

**Person.java:**

```
public class Person {

    private int age;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Name cannot be empty.")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @JsonSerialize(using = SexTypeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = SexTypeDeserializer.class)
    private Sex sex;

    //getters, setters, other methods
}
```

**TestConfig.groovy**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        def objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        def jacksonModule = new SimpleModule()
        jacksonModule.addDeserializer(Sex.class, new SexTypeDeserializer())
        jacksonModule.addSerializer(Sex.class, new SexTypeSerializer())

        objectMapper.registerModule(jacksonModule)
        objectMapper
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext$StubBeanFactory.createBean(StubWebApplicationContext.java:369)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.SpringHandlerInstantiator.deserializerInstance(SpringHandlerInstantiator.java:68)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.deserializerInstance(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:111)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findDeserializerFromAnnotation(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1436)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.constructSettableProperty(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:765)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:544)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:270)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:168)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:401)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:350)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:263)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:243)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializerCache.java:193)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializationContext.java:344)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canDeserialize(ObjectMapper.java:2035)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:151)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:187)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:148)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
```

Custom serializers are also provided and were working correctly with previous version of spring. I think that there is something wrong with configuration, because of fact that such method is being called:

**StubWebApplicationContext.java**

```
@Override
public <T> T createBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Looks like some other implementation of createBean should be used.
Any ideas where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a breaking change that was introduced in Spring Framework 4.1.3.

I have created a bug report to make sure that this gets resolved:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13375

Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

By the way, when you use `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup()`, there is **no** need to load an `ApplicationContext` via `@ContextConfiguration` and `@WebAppConfiguration`. If you analyze your test class, you will see that you are in fact not even using the `WebApplicationContext` that you have `@Autowired` into your test. Thus you can safely remove all of that configuration.

Note as well that your `TestConfig` is **not** used in `MockMvc` since you are using `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup()` to test an instance of your controller directly. In other words, your custom `SexTypeDeserializer` is not used in a test configured like this. If you want to continue to use the stand-alone setup, you can configure a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with your custom configured `ObjectMapper` (along with your custom serializer, etc.) and pass it to `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder` via its `setMessageConverters(...)` method.

As an alternative, you could consider using `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)` in order to actually use your `SexTypeDeserializer` in your tests along with the rest of your production Spring MVC configuration.

Comment: I had a similar problem.  Thank you for this answer. It pointed me in the right direction.